# Corrupt pagination buttons in DataTables.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying the basic [example of DataTables using a js array](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/Misc/Stack%20Exchange/html/table.html](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Everything is rendered well, except the pagination buttons to the bottom right. I tried fixing their css manually, but when the table is redrawn (paginated/# rows changed), it gets screwed up again.

Any idea how to get the prev/next buttons to be rendered ok?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is to re-apply the fixed CSS every time the table changes:

```
$('#example').on("draw", function() {
    //Change the CSS here
});
```

This way it will be fixed every time the table is "drawn" (sorted, page change, filter etc..)

But this does not solve the issue with it being broken in the first place. I'll update my answer if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the previous/Next text you can just remove it using oLanguage attrib below

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": { "oPaginate": {"sNext": "","sPrevious": ""}},
    "aaData": //rest fo your code.....
```

Else, download and add this css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/demo_table.css">
```

add olanguage attrib same as above with shorter text

```
"oLanguage": { "oPaginate": {"sNext": "Next","sPrevious": "Prev"}},
```

and modify the dataTables_paginate class in css above demo_table.css on line 71 to reduce font size of text

```
.dataTables_paginate {
    float: right;    
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Hope this helps..